# how to permanently redirect using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I need redirect from:

```
example.com/oldusers/Some-User  
to  
example.com/user/Some-User
```

Currently i have this rule

```
RewriteRule ^user/([^/]+)/?$ user.php?u=$1
```

Comment: now when come from google come from users/* and my folder structure is new now is user/*

Comment: and I get this 404 error Not Found

The requested URL /users/doni65 was not found on this server.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^users/([^/]+)/?$ http://example.com/user/$1 [R=301,L]
```

now working